# Error: permission denied on resource project when launching Dataproc cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I was successfully able to launch a dataproc cluster by manually creating one via `gcloud dataproc clusters create...`. However, when I try to launch one through a script (that automatically provisions and stops clusters), it says `ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.create) PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied on resource project hail-test-project (#0)`. I don't understand why, because the script uses the same command.

Answer (score 24):

One possible reason is you are using a wrong project. You should use your **project id**, not your project name. Sometimes they are the same, sometimes not. I just met this problem and I think this could be the possible reason, and it will be useful for other people that find this question in the future.

Comment: Works in my case. I just change project name to project id. ``gcloud config set project project-id``

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the script might be running as a different user than when you run `gcloud dataproc clusters create...` manually.  `gcloud` uses your home directory for configuration, so the body of your script will be dependent on the user it runs as.